# Pandas: Split DF into multiple csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
|100|Header1|Header2|
|120| xxx   | xxx   |
|120| yyy   | yyy   |
|120| zzz   | zzz   |
|200|Header3|Header4|
|220| xxx   | xxx   |
|220| yyy   | yyy   |
|220| zzz   | zzz   |
|300|Header5|Header6|
|320| xxx   | xxx   |
|320| yyy   | yyy   |
|320| zzz   | zzz   |
```

All headers start at a series of 100 which need to be split into it's individual csv file. So in this case there will be 3 csv files, with one having rows 100 and 120s, the second csv file with 200 and 220s and third with 300 and 320s.

The 100, 200 and 300 rows indicate the start of a new table. is there an efficient way to do this in pandas without having to loop through and create a new csv file if it encounters 100, 200 etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupby`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep = '|',header=None)
df.drop([0,4],axis = 1,inplace = True)
for i,sd in df.groupby(df[1]//100):
    sd.to_csv(f'test{i*100}.csv',index=False,header=False)
```

test.txt contains raw data provided by OP:

```
|100|Header1|Header2|
|120| xxx   | xxx   |
|120| yyy   | yyy   |
|120| zzz   | zzz   |
|200|Header3|Header4|
|220| xxx   | xxx   |
|220| yyy   | yyy   |
|220| zzz   | zzz   |
|300|Header5|Header6|
|320| xxx   | xxx   |
|320| yyy   | yyy   |
|320| zzz   | zzz   |
```

Output:

It would create 3 files `test100.csv`,`test200.csv` and `test300.csv`

test100.csv

```
100,Header1,Header2
120, xxx   , xxx   
120, yyy   , yyy   
120, zzz   , zzz
```

test200.csv

```
200,Header3,Header4
220, xxx   , xxx   
220, yyy   , yyy   
220, zzz   , zzz
```

test300.csv

```
300,Header5,Header6
320, xxx   , xxx   
320, yyy   , yyy   
320, zzz   , zzz
```

Comment: Getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @dev this should work for the structure of the text file you have provided (all the pipe `|` operators and all). If not so please provide a part of the original file you have.

Comment: `100|Header1|Header2|Header3
120|Val1|Val2|Val3
120|Val4||Val5
200|Header4|Header5
220|Val6|Val7
220|Val7|Val8
220|Val9|Val10`

Comment: @dev Ohh, remove the drop statement in my code and it should work for you

Comment: @dev also even after removing if it doesn't work, or there are some columns left with NA values, edit your question to include this data, as it is a bit hard to understand the structure of your data from comments.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a pure python approach

```
with open('test.csv') as fh:
    current_file_handle = None
    current_file_name = None
    for line in fh.readlines():
        p0 = line.find('|') + 1
        p1 = line[p0:].find('|') + p0
        if current_file_name != f'{line[p0]}00':
            current_file_name = line[p0:p1]
            current_file_handle = open(f'test_{current_file_name}.csv', 'w')
        current_file_handle.write(line)
    current_file_handle.close()
```